# If the number of equations in a linear system exceeds the number of unknowns, then the system must be inconsistent - FALSE. Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand how this statement is FALSE. What if a matrix resulted in a row which led us to row 0x2 = 9, which would tell us that the plane or vector is parallel?

Thanks in advance for clearing up my confusion.

Reference : This was from my linear algebra textbook.  Elementary Linear Algebra Tenth Edition by Howard Anton and Chris Rorres.

Chapter 1.1 True False exercise (e)

Comment: The statement in the title is false.

Comment: This was from my textbook, I added the reference. Yea I think it may be wrong as well..

Comment: The system $x+y+z=1,\ x+y+z=2$ is inconsistent. And what do you mean by "a matrix resulted in a row which led us to row 0x2 = 9": do you mean during Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Am i not reading the question properly? Let me change the title to match exactly what the book is saying

Comment: Yes, by Gaussian Elimination. The example you provided  we have more variables than equations, the question is asking for more equations than variables

Comment: The title say it's false... "I don't understand how this statement holds true" You don't understand how it's true that the stament is FALSE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key word here is *must*. I.e., the statement claims that *every* system of linear equations with more equations than unknowns is inconsistent. That’s false. For example, the system $$\begin{align}
x &= 1 \\
2x &= 2
\end{align}$$ has two equations and one unknown, but is clearly consistent.

Comment: Oh man, that definitely works. Wow what a way to confuse what they are trying to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the title isn't necessarily true. It's entirely possible for a system to be inconsistent even though the number of equations is greater than the number of variable.

Maybe the statement was taken out of context?

Comment: I changed the title, to exactly what the question says.